# Save a hash into a mysql record using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have a ruby hash :

```
person={:name=>:Alex,:age=>10}
```

I wish I could call an API like this:

```
db.save :people, person
```

which will execute the following SQL on mysql database:

```
insert  nto people (name,age) values ('Alex',10)
```

Is this possible by using rails or other ruby gems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call ClassName.create!(your_hash), so in your scenario it would look like this:

```
Person.create!(person) # to create a record right away
```

or

```
person = Person.new(person) # to initialize the object first

person.save #  and then save it
```

No need to use any external gems, this is standard ActiveRecord, one of the Rails core libraries.

Answer (score 0):

class Person < Activerecord::Base
end

put Person class in a models file. corresponding table name should be persons, Its a plural of model name and first letter will be lower case. Just see the convention for Rails.

Now try

```
Person.create!(attributes).
```

attributes are like column name corresponding value.

example

```
{:name => 'sandip'}  #here name is the column name and value is the 'sandip'
```